# make api calls from the front end

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I made a django application that uses restful apis to access the database. the apis are up and look great on the django url. Now i want to use javascript on the frontend to access them. where can I find a tutorial to show me how to do this?

I want to create a button that when I click it will render a picture to the screen. I want to use javascript only. meaning no help from django. This is a super simple process im sure. only I am so new to this I dont know how to go about it. I'm looking for either a solution, or an awesome tutorial to learn from. Thank you!

Comment: This would largely depend on what javascript framework or library etc. you are working with. Can you post more info about your environment, and some code you have tried so far? Otherwise, might be too broad of a question to answer in a helpful manner.

Comment: I'm trying to learn this without anything unnecessary. So plain ole js or jquery and ajax. ironically im a react developer during the day. but using react takes all the magic away. i have no idea how to work with javascript outside of the react framework. i was a python developer previously then several months ago transitioned into react. this is a side project so that i can actually learn my job. its so bewildering that i dont need to know javascript outside of basic syntax in order to work with react. to answer your question. assume i have a functioning api. I need to know how to access it.

Comment: I understand :) I have never coded a XHR by hand, because I am always working in an environment which has ajax utilities, such as jquery, angular, aurelia, etc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is by [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). A tutorial can be found [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) as well.

Comment: @Newbieee this is the only way that javascript can make a HTTP request.

Comment: @Lefty Technically hellol11 is correct, but there are libraries that let you do it more easily. Most popular one is called axios -- https://github.com/axios/axios